# XPath query not returning results during vs2010 publication

Tags: xpath, xdt-transform

I'm publishing a site using the vs 2010 built in xdt stuff.  I know the transformation is working because other elements of the web.config are getting transformed.

Here's the transform statement that is causing issues for me:

```
<param name="ssrsServiceUrl" value="thevalue" xdt:Locator="XPath   (/configuration/unity/container/register[@name='ReportingRegistration']/constructor/param[@name='ssrsServiceUrl'])" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(value)"/>
```

Here's the config file (relevant parts only)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
 <unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
  <container>
   <register name="ReportingRegistration" type="IMyType" mapTo="MyType">
    <lifetime type="singleton"/>
    <constructor>
     <param name="ssrsServiceUrl" value="foovalue"/>
    </constructor>
   </register>
  </container>
 </unity>
</configuration>
```

There are multiple parameters in the web.config that I omitted.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, the problem was the namespace defined in the unity block.  I took it out and that solved the problem.  I'm not exactly sure why it does that.  I believe it's a limitation to the XPath query parser implementation in .net, not XPath itself.